# JavaConfig: Replacing aop:advisor and tx:advice

Tags: spring

I'm wondering if I can map this piece of xml-configuration to Spring JavaConfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
  default-autowire="byName">

  <aop:config>
     <aop:pointcut id="serviceAnnotatedClass" expression="@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)" />
     <aop:advisor id="managerTx" advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceAnnotatedClass" order="20" />
  </aop:config>

  <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
      <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
      <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
      <tx:method name="load*" read-only="true" />
      <tx:method name="is*" read-only="true" />
      <tx:method name="ownTransaction*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" rollback-for="Exception" />
      <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Exception" />
    </tx:attributes>
  </tx:advice>

</beans>
```

So far I figured out how to replace **aop:pointcut** with

```
<aop:advisor id="managerTx" advice-ref="txAdvice" 
pointcut="com.myapp.configuration.AspectConfig.serviceAnnotatedClass()" order="20"/>
```

and

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class AspectConfig
{

  @Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)")
  public void serviceAnnotatedClass() {}
}
```

Any hints how to replace the rest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently it isn't possible to translate all XML-based AspectJ settings to a Java based configuration. Probably it will never be. The main reason is that Java doesn't support method literals. But there is a workaround, which was first presented here: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8148

> 1. Continue using `<aop:config>` by including the relevant XML snippet using `@ImportResource`
> 2. Convert any existing `<aop:config>` elements to use `@Aspect` style.

Referring to the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj), I would say that you're already nearly done with your configuration you have described above. You just have to change you config like this:

```
<aop:config>
     <aop:advisor id="managerTx" advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut="com.myapp.configuration.AspectConfig.serviceAnnotatedClass()" order="20" />
</aop:config>
```

Leave the rest like it is and import that resource:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
@ImportResource("classpath:/aop-config.xml")
public class AspectConfig
{
    @Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)")
    public void serviceAnnotatedClass() {}
}
```

I hope I could help...

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to use any xml at all, then you can create a separate Java configuration class for aspects

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.myAspects")
public class AspectConfig {
    //Here you can define Aspect beans or just use @ComponentScan (as above)
    //to scan the @Aspect annotation in com.myAspects package
}
```

And import above configuration class in your main AppConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({ AspectConfig.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "pkg1", "pkg2", "pkg3" })
public class AppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    //Other configuration beans or methods
}
```

Now create your aspect beans

```
import com.myAspects;
@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.service.*.*(..))")
    public void logBefore(){
        System.out.println("before advice called");
    } 

    @After("execution(* com.service.*.*(..))")
    public void logAfter(){
        System.out.println("after advice called");
    } 

}
```

You can use pointcut along with advice annotation as shown above.