# Spring Boot aop tx advice in java config without xml config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-transactions, spring-java-config

I have Spring boot application with Atomikos and JOOQ (with multiple data sources db1 & db2)
I have XML configuration like below and I want to convert it to java config.

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
    <tx:attributes>
        <!-- All methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
        <tx:method name="processNew*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"/>
        <tx:method name="onMessage*" propagation="SUPPORTS"/>
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

I have seen some stackoverflow question already asking this question, but they're old and haven't found any solution.

[JavaConfig: Replacing aop:advisor and tx:advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068525/javaconfig-replacing-aopadvisor-and-txadvice)

So want to know exact java configuration for provided XML configuration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38725266/1128953 this answer is already answered the question. and if you only want to add transaction the `@Transactional` annotation is a good choose for you.

Comment: i can add AOP but how do add start a new transaction when my method name starts with processnew.        <tx:method name="processNew*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"/>

Answer (score 1):

maybe later but solution in below works for me.

https://linuxtut.com/en/fc0e4145c5249c7f5f80/

```
    @Bean
    public BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor transactionAdvisor(
            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        RuleBasedTransactionAttribute attribute = new RuleBasedTransactionAttribute();
        attribute.setTimeout(30);
        attribute.getRollbackRules().add(new RollbackRuleAttribute(Exception.class));

        NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource source = new NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource();
        source.addTransactionalMethod("*", attribute);

        BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor advisor = new BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor(
);
        advisor.setTransactionAttributeSource(source);
        advisor.setAdvice(new TransactionInterceptor(transactionManager, source));
        // Implement filter conditions and`setClassFilter`Call
        advisor.setClassFilter(clazz -> AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(clazz, Service.class) != null);
        return advisor;
    }
```

Comment: helped a lot. 
a minor fix :`advisor.setClassFilter(clazz -> AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(clazz, Service.class).isPresent());` because it will always return`Optional` which is always not null

Answer (score 0):

I got solution which is almost nearer to above xml configuration.
In below solution i applied aop on bean name rather classes inside a package.

```
@Bean(name = "transactionInterceptor")
public TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor(PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager) {
    TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor = new TransactionInterceptor();
    transactionInterceptor.setTransactionManager(platformTransactionManager);
    Properties transactionAttributes = new Properties();
    transactionAttributes.setProperty("*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Throwable");
    transactionAttributes.setProperty("tranNew*", "PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,-Throwable");
    transactionInterceptor.setTransactionAttributes(transactionAttributes);
    return transactionInterceptor;
}

@Bean
public BeanNameAutoProxyCreator transactionAutoProxy() {
    BeanNameAutoProxyCreator transactionAutoProxy = new BeanNameAutoProxyCreator();
    transactionAutoProxy.setProxyTargetClass(true);
    transactionAutoProxy.setBeanNames("*Service");
    transactionAutoProxy.setInterceptorNames("transactionInterceptor");
    return transactionAutoProxy;
}
```